# Array of Structs Doubling Algorithm C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm trying to double the size of an array of structs. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct MyStruct{
    int num;
};

void arrayfunc(struct MyStruct arr[]){
    MyStruct *temp_arr = new MyStruct[6];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        temp_arr[i].num = arr[i].num;
    }

    temp_arr[3].num = 10;

    delete []arr;

    arr = temp_arr;

    }

int main(){
    MyStruct* arr = new MyStruct[3];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        arr[i].num = i;
    }

    arrayfunc(arr);

    cout << arr[3].num << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever my code is put back into my main script, it runs through the function just fine, but then crashes, I guess while trying to store more info. I tried returning the pointer to the array, but couldn't get it to work. Shouldn't changing the dynamic pointer change the array in main(), too? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you pass the array address by value.

When in `arrayfunc()` you perform `arr = temp_arr;` you are only changing the value of the parameter that is local to the function.   The original arr in main() remains unchanged.

You should pass the parameter by reference to work as you exepect:

```
void arrayfunc(struct MyStruct* &arr){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void arrayfunc(struct MyStruct arr[])
```

When calling this function, you're passing *a copy of* the pointer to the first element to it. The data itself is not copied, but the pointer is.

Now, you can change the pointer in the function, but main will have still the old one. Use a reference:

```
void arrayfunc(struct MyStruct &arr[])
```

or `std::vector`...

Btw., you're missing a `delete[]`

Comment: What do you mean I'm missing a delete? Do I need another one besides deleting the memory associated with the original array?

Comment: @MANA624 Yes, because you actually have two arrays. Currently, you delete only the one with size 3, but not the one with size 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = temp_arr;
```

this line is where your code fails to do as you wanted. a pointer variable is merely a numeric unsigned value with some basic type information.

when you set arr to something else, you changed the address, not the data referenced by the address you passed to the function.

you could do

```
arrayFunc(struct MyStruct **arr)
```

call it with

```
arrayFunc(&arr)
```

and use it within the function like

```
(*arr)[i].num
```

and delete it like

```
delete[] (*arr)
```